# Correct way to specify discretionary hyphens in bib files with biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, unicode, hyphenation, biber

Today I unexpectedly received the dreaded `character not set up for use with LaTeX` from `inputenc`. In this case, I was also pretty sure the error came from a `.bib` file. However, I grepped everything in the working directory as well as all `.bib` files and, just in case, all of my custom `.cls` and `.sty` files as well. The only place I could find the character was in ***generated*** files. That is, it did not appear to be in the ***source*** at all:

```
$ grep ‑ * ~/texmf/bibtex/bib/*.bib ~/texmf/tex/latex/cfr/* ~/texmf/tex/latex/config/*
```

executed from my working directory gave the following (plus a couple of innocuous complaints about non-file like things):

```
filename.bbl:        {Oxford University Press/Clar‑endon}%
filename.log:! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‑ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

That is, although the character is ***not*** in any of my source files, it ***is*** in the file `biber` generates.

I can reproduce the error using the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{mybook,
    title       =   {Great Book},
    author      =   {Author, Some},
    year        =   1055,
    publisher   =   {Oxford University Press/Clar\-endon},
    address     =   {Oxford}}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

  \autocite{mybook}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Obviously, there are a couple of options I can use to work around this. I could remove `\-` from the `.bib` file in question. Or I could declare the relevant unicode character which `biber` is inserting. Or I could define the discretionary hyphenation somewhere outside the `.bib` file, I guess.

However, this worked fine until recently. I've used `\-` in `Clar\-endon` for a long time and it has never caused any trouble before. So I assume something has changed in the way `biblatex`/`biber` responds to the entry in the file. (Perhaps I should add that it is not that the hyphenation is being invoked. There is no need to break the line in this case, as it happens.)

Which raises the question: what is the correct way to specify discretionary hyphenation in `.bib` files so that they work correctly with `inputenc` and `pdflatex` in UTF8 encoding without special workarounds?

Note that I do know about XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but I'm specifically interested in getting this to work with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Curiously, `\-` is mapped to U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN, which I'd consider a bug. However, I'd use `Press\slashb Clarendon`, where `\slashb` is defined to do `\slash\hspace{0pt}` (if you'd like to break at the slash) or `/\nobreak\hspace{0pt}` (if a break at `/` is not desired). You should also add `\hyphenation{Clar-en-don}` if you use the US hyphenation patterns that give just `Claren-don`; with British hyphenation patterns, you get `Clar-en-don`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. So probably I can just remove `\-` in this case if it should pick up the hyphenation patterns anyway. However, I guess my question remains since there certainly might be cases where it would be useful to specify a hyphenation point in a `.bib` file. I've had trouble with other escape sequences in `.bib` files since switching to `biblatex/biber`. Generally, I fix the errors by replacing the character with the unicode equivalent but I'm not sure that I should need to do this. (I know this is very counter-intuitive but something is odd about `biber`'s replacements.)

Comment: `Press/Clarendon` wouldn't be hyphenated, because of the slash, that's why I proposed `\slashb`.

Comment: I can't test now. But it sounds like a bug, so I suggest a bug report. Besides this: the replacements can be configured, see the biber documentation.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I realised that. I didn't think about the effect of the slash. I've just changed my definition of `/` as a bib file string to `\slash\hspace{0pt}`. However, I have other cases where I use `\-` in my `.bib` files where this doesn't apply. That is, I've changed everything I can find using `/` in `pub.bib` which is my list of publishers. But I still have things like `Harper\-San\-Francisco` so I would still like to know how to specify hyphenation points correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. I didn't think of `biber`'s doc as opposed to `biblatex` for some reason. So this is a `biber` bug rather than `biblatex`? I'm never sure what does which.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/46

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm still having trouble with this. Are you referring to the `--recodedata` option described on page 35? If so, is there a way to just tell it to leave `\-` alone or do I have to copy the entire file and edit it as described?

Comment: @egreg Any tricks for `Harper\-Collins`?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what you must do to use --recodedata, it's long ago that I looked into it. But why don't you use the development version as the bug is fixed there? Or simply redefine U+2011 in the document so that it does want you want?

Comment: @cfr `\newcommand\joiner{-}` and `Harper\joiner Collins`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug and should be fixed in the 2.0 DEV version of biber on SF. When decoding to UTF8, "\-" shouldn't really be touched.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and for fixing this so quickly!